# SVG <use> scales but <image> not

Tags: firefox, svg

I want to embed some SVG into SVG.
Therefor I want to use the <image> element since I want to keep my SVG separated.
But when I include my SVG like that:

```
<image xlink:href="svgs/munitionsmangel.svg" width="20" height="20" x="120" y="70" />
```

It works, but does not scale the SVG up when I zoom with my browser, it just stays small.

But when I embed just the same SVG file as a symbol and include it like that:

```
<use xlink:href="#munitionsmangel" width="20" height="20" x="80" y="70" />
```

it just scales up like a charm.
What is the problem here?

Edit: Seems like this is a bug with Firefox, in the current version 21
Chrome scales up the image as well...
Even more strange, if I include a raster image with image, both Firefox and Chrome scale it...

Edit 2: Even IE 9 has the desired behaviour, although its rendering of background colors is a bit strange, so its only Firefox which sucks

Comment: Can you add which browser you've tried?

Comment: Thanks for the Edit suggestions and fix of the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this really seems like a bug in Firefox, I will use the `<use />`-tag instead, maybe in combination with XMLHttpRequest to insert the `<symbol />` dynamically.
Or even only XMLHttpRequest with inserting the node directly.
I cannot think of a better solution, so if there is really a better answer, just post it!

Comment: Why the hell did it leave out the tags when I wrote it?
I am absolutely sure that I used them.